# How to convert sbt 0.12 "<<= map case" to sbt 1.x

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt 0.12 build.sbt

```
val myTask = TaskKey[Unit]("mytask")
lazy val baseSettings = Seq(
    javacOptions ++= Seq("-g", "-encoding", "utf8")
)
lazy val appSettings = baseSettings ++ Seq(
  myTask <<= (fullClasspath in Runtime, normalizedName, target, packageOptions, streams, cacheDirectory) map {
    case (fullClasspath: Classpath, normalizedName: String, target: File, packageOptions: Seq[PackageOption], streams: TaskStreams, cacheDirectory: File) => {
      streams.log.info("my task appSettings")
    }
  }
)
```

Want to update the following code to sbt 1.x

```
myTask <<= (fullClasspath in Runtime, normalizedName, target, packageOptions, streams, cacheDirectory) map {
    case (fullClasspath: Classpath, normalizedName: String, target: File, packageOptions: Seq[PackageOption], streams: TaskStreams, cacheDirectory: File) => {
```

Thank you

```
Update:
I find some information at scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html, but I don't know how to use ":=" with "case"
```

```
EDIT:
Mateusz Kubuszok is right, not need "case", and "cacheDirectory" can be replaced by "streams.value.cacheDirectory"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<<=` you use `:=`.

Instead of tuple of settings and `map`, you simply call `.value` on key/settings.

`cacheDirectory` was removed.

Since 1.1 there is also [unified path syntax](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/scala-sbt-110-patchnotes)

```
lazy val appSettings = Seq(
  myTask := {
    streams.value.log.info(s"my task appSettings: ${(Runtime / fullClasspath).value}, ${normalizedName.value}, ${target.value}, ${packageOptions.value}")
  }
)
```

In more complex tasks you might need to consult the documentation about e.g. [order of execution](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Sequencing.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will modify the script and update the results